# Auto inputting text to textbox on exterior website after clicking link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there would be a way to have or implement so that when a link is clicked on my website, it takes you to another website with a textbox and auto inputs a number or string.

What I essentially am trying to do with more detail.

I have a website that advertises product. It's a website that sells things based off of commission. I have a link on the website that links to another business website and has an input box to input an ID number in order for the website to know which item they are buying based off of an ID number, when the link is clicked, it takes them there and they would manually have to type it in. I was wondering if there was a way that when they click the corresponding link, it would take them to said website and automatically add the ID into the textbox so they wouldn't have to memorize or copy/paste.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to stack overflow. Please post some code that you have tried so far for the community to look at.

Comment: I was looking into Jquery on other questions, but I can't seem to pinpoint which route I should use. Most of the stuff I have found is their website based. I'll compile a list of a few things I have tried that have got me nowhere close to anything but a broken link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variable through `URL`

> http://wwww.example.com/index.html?var=yournumber

You can get that var using PHP GET method or Jquery

**jQuery**

```
var url      = window.location.href; 
var number = url.substr(val.indexOf("?") + 1);
```

**PHP**

```
 $number = $_GET['var'];
```

**Remeber one thing**: Inorder to achieve this you must have access to the second website.
You can retrieve variable from second site only if you have access to that site..

```
jQuery("#id of input field").val(number);

jQuery("#id of input field").val("<?php echo $number; ?>");
```